Insert a column that depends from the previous row already inserted
I have a table in PL/SQL called TABLE_1 with five columns like this:

I want to create a new table TABLE_2, which has the same data but adding a new column c5 like the following:

The column c5 has been calculated as follows:

When c2 = 1 just c1*c4
Else, (c1 - lag(c3) - lag(c5))*c4.

As an example, the second row will be: (5000 - 200 - 3870.60)*0.10 = 96.05.
I don't know how to do this for a large amount of data, thank you in advance

You can use a MODEL clause:
CREATE TABLE table_2 (id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) AS
SELECT id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5
FROM   table_1
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (id)
  DIMENSION BY (c2)
  MEASURES (c1, c3, c4, 0 AS c5)  
  RULES SEQUENTIAL ORDER (
    c5[1] = c1[1] * c4[1],
    c5[c2>1] = (c1[cv(c2)] - c3[cv(c2) - 1] - c5[cv(c2) - 1]) * c4[cv(c2)]
  )  
ORDER BY id, c2;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_1 (id, c1, c2, c3, c4) AS
SELECT 1, 5000, 1,  200, 0.77 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5000, 2,  410, 0.10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5000, 3,  630, 0.04 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5000, 4,  860, 0.84 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5000, 5, 1100, 0.03 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 5000, 6, 1350, 0.18 FROM DUAL;

Then table_2 contains:



ID
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5




1
5000
1
200
.77
3850


1
5000
2
410
.1
95


1
5000
3
630
.04
179.8


1
5000
4
860
.84
3519.768


1
5000
5
1100
.03
18.60696


1
5000
6
1350
.18
698.6507472



Note: I think your c4 values have been rounded to 2 decimal places as 3870.60 is 5000 * 0.77412 and not 5000 * 0.77 this means that the outputs do not match your values (because we do not have your full values, only the rounded values).
fiddle

NB: this works at the condition that C2 is really what it looks like: a row number inside the ID partition, if not it should be replaced by a generated row_number() over(partition...) column to guarantee unique addressing of the rows in the DIMENSION.

Just a note that SEQUENTIAL ORDER could be ommited as it is default for RULES clause.

One option is to create a recursive cte joining previous row of table_1 with current row of cte and then select just rows whose recursion step number (column pass) equals c2 column - assuming c2 column is row number per id. If c2 is not row number per id then you should add another column with Row_Number() Over() analytic function to use it's value in the where clause (see the last code).
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table table_1 (id, c1, c2, c3, c4) AS
Select 1, 5000, 1,  200, 0.77 From Dual Union All 
Select 1, 5000, 2,  410, 0.10 From Dual Union All 
Select 1, 5000, 3,  630, 0.04 From Dual Union All 
Select 1, 5000, 4,  860, 0.84 From Dual Union All 
Select 1, 5000, 5, 1100, 0.03 From Dual Union All 
Select 1, 5000, 6, 1350, 0.18 From Dual;

WITH    --  R e c u r s i v e    C T E : 
    grid (pass, id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) AS
      ( Select   1, id, c1, c2, c3, c4, Case When c2 = 1 Then c1 * c4 Else 0 End as c5
        From     table_1
       UNION ALL
        Select   g.pass + 1, t.id, t.c1, t.c2, t.c3, t.c4,
                 Case When t.c2 > 1 Then ( t.c1 - g.c3 - g.c5 ) * t.c4
                 End
        From     table_1 t
        Inner Join grid g ON(g.id = t.id And g.c2 = t.c2 - 1)
        Where    g.pass < ( Select Count(id) From table_1 Where id = t.id )
      )

--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 
From   grid
Where  pass = c2
Order By id, c2

/*    R e s u l t :
ID    C1  C2    C3     C4     C5
--  ----  --  ----  -----  ------------
 1  5000    1   200  0.77          3850
 1  5000    2   410  0.10            95
 1  5000    3   630  0.04         179.8
 1  5000    4   860  0.84      3519.768
 1  5000    5  1100  0.03      18.60696
 1  5000    6  1350  0.18   698.6507472    */

See the fiddle here.
SQL code in case that c2 is not row number per id - same result as above
WITH    
  --  CTE with Row_Number() Over() column to be used instead of c2 
   ord_tbl_1 as 
      ( Select t.*, Row_Number() Over(Partition By t.id Order By t.c2) as rn
        From   table_1 t
      ),
  --  R e c u r s i v e    C T E :
    grid (pass, id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, rn) AS
      ( Select   1, id, c1, c2, c3, c4, Case When c2 = 1 Then c1 * c4 Else 0 End, rn
        From     ord_tbl_1
       UNION ALL
        Select   g.pass + 1, t.id, t.c1, t.c2, t.c3, t.c4,
                 Case When t.c2 > 1 Then ( t.c1 - g.c3 - g.c5 ) * t.c4
                 End, t.rn
        From     ord_tbl_1 t
        Inner Join grid g ON(g.id = t.id And g.rn = t.rn - 1)
        Where    g.pass < ( Select Count(id) From table_1 Where id = t.id )
      )

--    M a i n    S Q L : 
Select id, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 
From   grid
Where  pass = rn
Order By id, c2

Create your second table as one of the above SQL codes ...
